# multilingual application, which font sets to embed in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, internationalization

Building a multilingual application that should work with the most prevalent global alphabets but confused as to which font sets I should embed.

For instance for Chinese there is Traditional Level 1, Simplified,Traditional (all). and Chinese (all).

For Japanese there is Kani, Kanji, and All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need everything, unless you explicitly know that you won't need it. Some languages use multiple alphabets/syllabaries, and excluding any means that your language support will be broken.